# Planned Value (PV): why amount of work is spread evenly on timeline?

Tags: pmp, pmbok, pmi-framework

I have a basic confusion on Planned value calculation.

Example:
BAC* : 1000
Time: 4 weeks

after 2nd week, PV** should be 500

However, in my opinion, this sometimes does not hold true in an actual scenario.
Suppose I have to build a Table and paint it with a costly/exotic paint, which is around 600 and the labor cost is 100/week.

So, up to the third week, my efforts will be spent only on building the table, 4th week will be used for painting.

In the above scenario, at the end of the second week, my AC will come up as 200.

This will result in SV*** as 200 - 500 =-300 (negative). it will look like I am behind schedule.

I wanted to know how to handle this situation.

```
* BAC: Budget At Completion. Total Budget, the sum of all budgets.
** PV: Planned Value. A BAC fraction with the budget for a particular activity.
*** SV: Schedule Variance. A positive amount indicates you're ahead of schedule.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the fully costed resources against your work packages in the sequence you laid them out in the network logic. Your scheduling tool will then calculate the PV based on how YOU loaded it. The manner in which costs are spent is completely under your control. How this is performed depends on the tool you are using. You need to hire the proper skill set, someone who knows how to work the tools you are using, to do this properly.

As an aside, I would suggest avoiding measuring schedule using Earned Value, which measure the variance of money or % complete on the y-axis. Instead, use Earned Schedule, which measures variance of time, on the x-axis. This is far more accurate and has a significantly higher predictive capability.

[Earned Schedule](https://www.earnedschedule.com/)